# Load external JavaScript synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, eval

I have to add a script tag via some JavaScript *and* have it execute in full as the later statements rely on it.

```js
var logIt = (function() {
  var i = 0,
    logging = document.getElementById('logging');
  return function(s) {
    var heading = document.createElement('p');
    heading.innerText = `${++i}:  ${s}`;
    logging.appendChild(heading);
  }
}());

logIt('starting');
var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
newScriptTag.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js';
newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(newScriptTag);
try {
  var now = moment().format('HH:mm');
  logIt(`moment loaded.  The time is ${now}`);
} catch (e) {
  logIt(`Moment not loaded: ${e}`);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Injecting Script Tags</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Injecting Script Tags</h1>
  <div id="logging"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

As the snippet above shows, the `moment()` isn't available on the statement after the tag insertion.

I *think* it could be done with `eval(...)`, but that option isn't popular.

Comment: ever heard of `onload`?

Comment: @GottZ Yes.  Due to come compiling/transpiling/compressing/uglification it's not an option though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onload` event listener on the `<script>` tag:

```
const URL = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js';

const onMomentReady = () => {
  console.log('Moment.js is loaded!');
  console.log(typeof moment);
}

var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
newScriptTag.onload = onMomentReady;
newScriptTag.src = URL;
// newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; // no need for this

// optional
newScriptTag.async = true;
document.head.appendChild(newScriptTag);
```

Note that I added the `onload` handler *before* setting the `src` attribute. If you set the `src` first, *the handler function might not fire*.

Comment: Doesn't this still run moment async?  I can't call `moment()` in the same script, bar within the `onMomentReady()` method (and after it's been fired).

Comment: Not sure what you expected. Of course, it _does_ run the `onMomentReady` function asynchronously, because your browser cannot start to load moment before it has loaded, processed & executed the JS which creates the `<script>` tag. Also, the process of loading does consume time and is therefor async by it's nature – even if you don't put the `async` attribute onto the `<script>` tag.

Comment: just to add to this: not doing stuff async / event oriented in js is extremely bad practice and considered a anti pattern.

Comment: @GottZ I have to work with framework I have and I can't async it because it's there's stuff outside my control that will be bundled into it.

Comment: nothing is impossible. and unless you name that "framework" we cannot help you at all. also if you really need moment then why don't you bundle it into the framework? relying on a third party cdn could result in a possible 404 exception